# Failed to access LoadBalancer outside cluster with MetalLB

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using Kubespray with MetalLB. I managed to create a service with LoadBalancer. The thing is, the external IP is only accessible by either of the VM nodes only.

FYI, the VM nodes are: 10.214.47.21, 10.214.47.22, and 10.214.47.23 (all are acting as both worker and controller).

The load balancer external IP generated by the LB is 10.214.47.1. A sibling VM (the same 10.214.47/24 but not the cluster VMs) can ping to it, but can't access the service using curl. The exact curl only works within one of the 3 cluster VMs. Both cluster and the sibling VM have their firewalld off/dead.

Here's my config during Kubespray setup, specific to MetalLB sake:

addons.yml:

```
+metallb_enabled: true
+metallb_speaker_enabled: false
+metallb_protocol: "layer2"
+metallb_config:
+   controller:
+     nodeselector:
+       kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
+     tolerations:
+       - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane"
+         operator: "Equal"
+         value: ""
+         effect: "NoSchedule"
+   address_pools:
+     primary:
+       ip_range:
+         - 10.214.47.0/24
+       auto_assign: true
+       avoid_buggy_ips: true # When set to true, .0 and .255
```

k8s-net-calico.yml:

```
+calico_advertise_service_loadbalancer_ips: "{{ metallb_config.address_pools.primary.ip_range }}"
```

What did I do wrong here?